# Strange behaviour syncing between Outlook and Nokia Suite

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2013, nokia-pc-suite

Until recently I was syncing contacts no problem, now suddenly after syncing, Nokia Suite tells me there was a problem. I must repair or reinstall Outlook. I have just repaired Outlook  with no difference. The message also mentions configuring my user account, but I can find no user account setting relevant to synchronising. The only user account settings I can find at all are in fact those on my GMail account in Outlook. That is my 'mail server.

The Nokia Suite message ends with a mysterious "Error code: 83860077" without telling where the error code originated.

PS: I am using the latest "Nokia Suite" 3.6.36, not Ovi Suite or anything. This problem seems very common with Ovi.